# Adding LiveSDK via NuGet VS 2017

Tags: c#, uwp, live-sdk

Whenever I try to add the Microsoft.LiveSDK to a UWP the assembly is not recognized and right clicking in the Solution Explorer shows no properties.

When adding a a "using Microsoft."  has no Live assembly.

I am trying to use the LiveAuthClient.

My app targets NET 4.0

Everything works fine when developing using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

[Live SDK](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK) seems to be deprecated now. It has been replaced by the [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.com/) and [Microsoft Grpah SDKs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks).

[LiveSDK-for-Windows](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows) is still available for Windows 8.1/ Windows Phone 8.1, but may not for UWP app. It hasn’t yet been updated for UWP.

So if you are developing a UWP app, please use Microsoft Graph instead.